How to handle a haram relationship?
Asalamu ailaikum.
I just want to know what I have to do, recently I have been learning more about Islam and knowing about haram relationship, i am currently in a haram relationship, it's been two days i realized things and I wanted to break it up completely and return to my Allah  and seek forgiveness for the sins I have committed, I said to him that I wanted to end this but it ended up in a bad way he started saying that i have no one left but now Allah wants to take you also away from me go and say to your Allah that i have no Allah (nauzibillah) i had this guilt in my heart that he doing this wrong and is suffering also because of me how am I gonna face it , while I had also started praying tahajud but today i missed it cuz I was tired but when I woke up it felt like my soul was burning even my heart was too , that how could i miss it, and today also I said I want to end this but it ended up in a bad way and he got badly sick and after that in evening at time of Magrib namaz I felt my soul and heart are both burning, my soul wants to worship Allah but my heart is holding me back and i am suffering in between i don't know what to do plzz help me i am suffering in both ways. Tell me what should I do.

The fact will not change that haram relationship is haram. Either ask him to marry as soon as possible and until then don't indulge in any intimacy or other haram stuffs.
